# Has the ::-webkit-selection selector ever been supported?

Tags: css, webkit, css-selectors, pseudo-element

There are a few references on the internet to `::-webkit-selection`, a WebKit-specific version of [the `::selection` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#UIfragments).

See e.g. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html (**Edit:** PPK has since removed `::-webkit-selection` from that page.)

However, I haven’t been able to get the example in the page above, or my own examples, to work in any WebKit-based browser. I’ve tried:

- Safari

  - 1.0
  - 1.2
  - 2.0
  - 3.0
  - 4.0
  - 5.0
  - 5.1
- Chrome

  - 2
  - 6
  - 14

**The unprefixed `::selection` selector works in all of these browsers anyway, so it’s not really a problem.** But I was wondering where the references to the WebKit-specific version of this selector had come from.

Has anyone ever used it?

Comment: not sure but I think it works on the mobile browser versions like on the iPhone...

Comment: @Yahia: hm — I’ve tried the test page above on iOS 4.3.5, and neither `::-webkit-selection` nor `::selection` work.

Comment: iOS uses a custom selection control which would explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: `::selection` is supported by Safari 1.3 and later (probably even starting from 1.0), as well as all versions of Chrome and any other browser that uses WebKit. [MDN lists `::selection` as the one used by WebKit-based browsers too.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3aselection) I wouldn't be surprised if the prefixed version was made up by people ignorant enough to assume every named thing in CSS3 has to have all the vendor prefixes. As to why it's on a site like quirksmode.org, I'm not sure, but good to check with PPK himself.

Comment: @BoltClock - Possibly because the quirksmode page was posted well over a year ago and hasn't been updated.

Comment: @Rob: perhaps, but I’ve tested it in versions of Safari that were around then. As far as I can tell, the selector has never been supported in WebKit.

Comment: I'm thinking of dropping a bounty since nobody but a person who can't read has passed by since you posted :/

Comment: @BoltClock: yeah, no response from PPK as of yet. I have purchased an old PowerPC Mac, so I will check in Safari 1.0 at some point.

Comment: Just for the record, `::selection` is no longer in CSS3 — it may return in CSS4 UI, but nobody knows right now. I'll leave that [css3] tag in anyway, though...

Comment: Looks like PPK has updated the page, finally.

Comment: @BoltClock: ah yes, no `::-webkit-selection` on PPK's page any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve tested all the way back to Safari 1.0 (using [Multi-Safari](http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/)), and no version supports `::-webkit-selection` (and they all *do* support `::selection`).

Unless this is an issue with Multi-Safari, `::-webkit-selection` has never been supported in Safari post-1.0. I guess it might have been in the [public beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#History_and_development) though.

Comment: Is it true that it still supports `::selection`?  It doesn't appear to work in iOS 9 for me and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection claims its not supported for iOS 8 or 9.

Comment: @JonBrooks: no idea, I only tested the versions stated in the question. Interesting that support got removed.