# ::selection background-color and color rendering in browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, selection, background-color

### Issue

Using the following just simply doesn't work properly in `-webkit-` and `-moz-` browsers:

```
#exampleElement {
    background-color: red; /* For example */
}

#exampleElement ::selection {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

### Result: WebKit- and Blink-powered browsers

In Chrome, Opera, and Safari, `::selection`'s `background-color` renders as if it was 50% alpha but the font colour is correct.

Chrome 29.0.1547.62:
[image: Chrome 29.0.1547.62]

Opera 15.0.1147.130:
[image: Opera 15.0.1147.130]

Safari 5.34.57.2:
[image: Safari 5.34.57.2]

### Result: Gecko-powered browsers

In Firefox, the entire `::selection` rule is ignored. `::selection`'s `background-color` just happens to be white due to `#exampleElement`'s dark `background-color` (thanks to @BoltClock for noticing that)

Firefox 22.0:
[image: Firefox 22.0]

### Result: Trident-powered browsers

In Internet Explorer, (would you believe) everything is rendered perfectly.

Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16660:
[image: Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16660]

Is this just a flaw of these rendering engines / browsers or are there `-webkit-` and `-moz-` alternatives that I'm unaware of?

I've saved an example of this on jsFiddle, for people to see: http://jsfiddle.net/BWGJ2/

Comment: Yes, amazing as it may seem, IE9 *does actually work*!

Comment: Firefox is actually ignoring the entire `::selection` rule - its default highlight background just *happens* to be white if it determines that the parent background is dark enough not to use blue as a background.

Comment: @BoltClock Good spotting. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html), `-webkit-selection` and `-moz-selection` are indeed available. I just tested it with Chrome (18) and Firefox (13) and can confirm that it works with Firefox, but I didn't have success with `-webkit-selection` on Chrome (it ignored it), and according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545550/has-the-webkit-selection-selector-ever-been-supported) it doesn't exist (and the answer says that `::selection` *should* also work on all browser, but doesn't for me, too).

As already metioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224621/458274), Chrome forces the selection to be transparent, but you can work around this using

```
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99);
```

For more details, checkout the linked answer by tw16

---

Furthermore, this works for me on FF:

```
::selection { /* stuff */ }
::-moz-selection { /* stuff */}
```

But this does not:

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection { /* stuff */ }
```

But maybe this is not related to `::selection` but does apply on all pseudo elements, couldn't find an answer to that.

Comment: I see. So, ignore `-webkit-selection` then. Hmm. The RGBA method didn't work for me in Chrome 19? :/ http://jsfiddle.net/MythOfEchelon/a9ZZ5/6/

Comment: Aw, sorry, made a mistake in my answer. You need to use `0.99` instead of `1`, for some reasone, Chrome makes it transparent if you use 1. Going to edit the answer.

Comment: The reason why you need to split up the rules is detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302172/firefox-moz-selection-selector-bug-is-there-a-workaround This applies to all selectors, not just pseudo-elements. Note also that [WebKit deliberately ignores this rule for pseudo-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317954/ignoring-webkit-specific-css-selector-in-firefox), but that isn't relevant here since it already uses the unprefixed `::selection`.

Answer (score 0):

There are [browser-dependent versions](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html).  The version you're using was the standard CSS3 way, but then it got [dropped from the spec](http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2011/11/02/css3-selection-colors/).  I dunno about its browser support...

And something else to consider:  An ID-based CSS selector might "[outweigh](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)" a pseudoclass-based selector, resulting in the ID-based CSS always taking precedence.  So try adding `!important` to your `::selection` style to make sure it's always used when applicable.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Odd that using the appropriate browser-dependent versions is just as ineffective and sometimes even less effective.. http://jsfiddle.net/MythOfEchelon/a9ZZ5/3/

Comment: @BenHooper - The Mozilla-specific version (mistakenly applied to the "Webkit" div) was the only one that worked for me (Firefox 12.0 on Fedora).  It did correctly override the ID-based selector, at least.  I sure do hate browsers sometimes...

Comment: It was dropped because its definition in CSS3 was incomplete at best, so there never really was a "standard" to adhere to. Also, `::selection` is a pseudo-element, which has even less weight than a pseudo-class.