# Text Selection Color With CSS in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I want to the text selection color with CSS in the Chrome browser.have added this CSS, but it only works in Firefox. Does anyone know why it is not working in Chrome?

```
:selection  {
    background: #D03E27;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #D03E27;
}
```

Comment: `::-webkit-selection` ??

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 35 as is.

Comment: I tried. but does'nt work in Chrome @Paulie_D

Comment: `::selection` works fine in Chrome as is : http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9EX5W/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/umefx here is demo for it, you need to add webkit css for it.

Comment: Thank You EveryOne for giving response.
It works for me By adding (*) in front of ::-webkit-selection.
*::-webkit-selection {   background: #cc0000;   color: #ffffff; }

Comment: @VikasRana: Your code working on Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8mY/ OR see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545550/has-the-webkit-selection-selector-ever-been-supported. Why use ::-webkit-selection ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `::-webkit-selection { background:#D03E27; }` in order to achieve this in Google Chrome.

Comment: Why use ::-webkit-selection ?

Comment: I suggest you to read articles about it, [this one for example](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

Comment: Yes, I understand this but in chrome "::selection" is working fine.

Comment: Not every Chrome version.

Comment: ok no problem, but it's working in all most versions of chrome. Look here caniuse.com/css-selection